# Using Jenkins to deploy to staging and production based on condition

Tags: jenkins, deployment, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, continuous-deployment

My project has a Jenkinsfile that runs smoothly. The problem is that I need to run some commands only on certain occasions. I'm using the Github plugin. I need to run the deploy only when it is in the master or a new tag, one will be for staging and the other will be production.

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('Test') {
      steps {
        sh 'node -v'
        sh 'yarn install'
        sh 'yarn test -- --coverage'
      }
    }
    stage('Build') {
      steps {
        sh 'yarn build'
      }
    }
    stage('Deploy') {
      steps {
        sh 'aws s3 sync ./build s3://my.bucket --only-show-errors'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I need the master to deploy to a bucket and when it is new tag to another. How can I create this conditional?

Answer (score 0):

How about the following working as two conditionals for two separate deployment scenarios? I think it's better to work with this using variables to indicate deployment scenarios instead of splitting this to two distinctly different steps though. You could for example write a shell script that would handle everything inside depending on tags/branches/whatever you need instead of forcing yourself to control this on pipeline level.

Each stage will have it's steps executed only when `when` part is satisfied. Stage `Deploy` will only work for `master` branch, while stage `Deploy_NonMaster` will only work any non master branch. Using the method written in `when` conditionals you can check for anything, including tags or whatnot.

```
stage ('Deploy') {

        when {
            expression {
                GIT_BRANCH = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD').trim()
                return (GIT_BRANCH == 'master')
            }
        }
        steps {
            echo 'Do stuff/deploy.'
        }
    }
stage ('Deploy_NonMaster') {

        when {
            expression {
                GIT_BRANCH = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD').trim()
                return !(GIT_BRANCH == 'master')
            }
        }
        steps {
            echo 'Do stuff/deploy.'
        }
    }
```

Comment: This would deploy commits on any branch. I need o master and tag release, is this possible?

Comment: @IbnClaudius, modified the answer to include the explanation of how `when` conditionals work. Note the `!(GIT_BRANCH == 'master') in `Deploy_NonMaster` stage which expliticly states that this stage is executed for branches other than master.

Comment: But I need to deploy on changes on master and on github tag releases. On master deploy to staging and on tag to production. Where in your Jenkinsfile is the condition that runs only on tags?

Comment: @IbnClaudius you can do `git describe HEAD` instead of retrieving the branch name in `expression`. Then, if there's a tag - do something else than when there isn't a tag.

Comment: Would your solution find out if there's a new tag (as opposed to just having a tag)? Because as I understand that would be a proper trigger for deploying to production

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it with the Multibranch Pipeline feature of Jenkins. Check out this document https://www.jenkins.io/doc/tutorials/build-a-multibranch-pipeline-project/#add-deliver-and-deploy-stages-to-your-pipeline